# How to for loop to count each "male" in the array

Tags: php, count

I am trying to figure out how to use loops with count tag on php for the first time. It will be highly appreciated if you could point me in the right direction

```
$people = [
  ['name' => 'Allan', 'gender' => 'male'],
  ['name' => 'Rhea', 'gender' => 'female'],
  ['name' => 'Jane', 'gender' => 'female'],
];

$counterMale = 0;

//insert loop to count the "male"
//insert loop to count the 'female'

echo "Male count is $counterMale";
```

Comment: put an `if` while loop and count

Comment: Can you elaborate? having troubles with loop

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to post it as comment but looks like i can't comment because i don't have enough reputations, so posting it as answer.

You just have to iterate over `$people` array and then for each array you have to check whether `array["gender"]` is `male` or `female` and increase the respective counter.
Here is the code snippet:

```
$people = [
  ['name' => 'Allan', 'gender' => 'male'],
  ['name' => 'Rhea', 'gender' => 'female'],
  ['name' => 'Jane', 'gender' => 'female'],
];

$counterMale = 0;
$counterFemale = 0;

foreach($people as $p)
{
    if($p['gender'] == "male")
    {
        ++$counterMale;
    }
    else if($p['gender'] == "female")
    {
        ++$counterFemale;
    }
}

echo "Male count is ". $counterMale.PHP_EOL;
echo "Female count is ". $counterFemale;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$people = [
  ['name' => 'Allan', 'gender' => 'male'],
  ['name' => 'Rhea', 'gender' => 'female'],
  ['name' => 'Jane', 'gender' => 'female'],
];

echo array_count_values(array_column($people, 'gender'))['male'];
// male count with case sensitive 
// without single value throw error
```

For more details refer [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)